# What algorithm should I use to solve the stopping postman exercise?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve the stopping postman problem, but I'm not able to find any algorithm to solve it. The problem is this:

> There are n houses numbered 1 to n, and n postman, each having n
>   letters to be posted in each house. The postmaster has decided a plan
>   such that each postman visits each house exactly once at a different
>   time, i.e. there is at most one postman in any house at any time. 
>   Since no postman like any other , postmaster wants that no postmaster
>   meet any other  during delivery of posts to n houses. So he wants a
>   postman to stop posting after a particular house. That is, Postmaster
>   wants to find a sequence **stop** such that the **i-th** postman will
>   stop posting after **stop[i]-th** house once he visits that house. As
>   he wants to ensure that there is at maximum one post in each house, he
>   must choose the sequence **stop** such that if postman A visits house
>   H at time T, and he stops posting after the house, then no other
>   postman visit house H after time T. Help postmaster to find such a
>   sequence **stop**.

The input is given as follows:

Firstly **n** (1 ≤ **n** ≤ 100), indicating the number of postman and houses. Then **n** lines follow, with each line containing **n** positive integers. The **j-th** integer in **i-th** line indicates the time when the **i-th** postman will visit the **j-th** house.

Example:
n = 3

The sequence is :

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 9

The outputted **stop** array should be:

`3 2 1`, i.e. 1st postman stops posting in 3rd house, 2nd in 2nd house and 3rd in first house.

What algorithm should I use to solve this problem?

Comment: I first sorted the order of postman in each house. Then beginning from the first stopped the last postman to that house. If he is last in more than one, then stopped him to that house in which he came earliest.

Comment: After trying few steps it is getting difficult to device a procedure for the whole problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, my last answer was wrong.

New solution:
on each step find min number in each row, then take the max of them and that will be the stop for i-th postman. on each next step don't consider that postman anymore

For the sample you provided:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

1st step we find 1 4 7, maximum of them is 7 so for the 3rd postman stop is at 1st house(stop[3] = 1)
after that we don't consider 1st column and 3rd row
2nd step we find 2 and 5, max is 5 so - stop[2] = 2;
3rd step stop[1] = 3;

So, why is it true, if we selected the right number on some step we know that for any number in the same column, it's either less than our number (that means it won't cause problem later) or bigger that our number, but that row has the number which is less than it WILL be selected later, so that that the bigger number in our column won't be used

And for the example @Wayne Rooney provided

```
1 4 2
8 6 9
5 7 3
```

1st step find 1, 6, 3, select 6
2nd step find 1, 3 select 3
3rd step 1
answer: 1, 2, 3

Comment: Is there any case where no solution is possible?

Comment: As I understand it, there is always a solution. But, check it yourself, I could be wrong.

Comment: I am sure there exist atleast one such case but not able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

@Herokiller Your algorithm is incorrect .
Take for eg:

1 4 2

8 6 9

5 7 3

Your output would be:

Step1: take tuple (8,7,3) min of which is 7 then take (8,9) so min is 8 and finally (2)
So output is 3,1,2

But answer is going to be 1 2 3 i.e.(1,6,3)

Even I dont know the answer to this question but I had a contradictory test case and I could not comment on your message because It was marked as right answer

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, please, check my new answer.